# Hope for any help with this delta function question

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't know how to show X is a vector space and what does "onto" mean......
Let X be the collection of functions u in $C^\infty(R^2)$ that vanish outside a ball(Each u has its own ball) and $Z = R^2$. Define the gradient of the delta function:
$\iint_{R^2}\nabla\delta(x)u(x)dx = -\nabla\ u(0)$.  Show that $\nabla\delta : X \to Z $ is a linear operator. Is $\nabla\delta$ onto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linearity of the operator is due to the linearity of the gradient:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \nabla \delta(x) (\alpha u(x)+\beta v(y)) \ dx=-\nabla(\alpha u(0)+\beta v(0))= -\alpha\nabla u(0)-\beta\nabla v(0) $$
Therefore if $F(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \nabla \delta(x)u(x) dx$ we have $F(\alpha u + \beta v)= \alpha  F(u)+\beta F(v)$.

Now, if you want to show that the operator is surjective (onto) you have to ask yourself the following question: For every $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ Can I find a $C^\infty$ function $u(x)$ such that $-\nabla u(0)=(a,b)$? Take $u(x,y)=ax+by$ (except in a ball) for example.